# What are 'weak references' in KiokuDB?

Tags: perl, serialization, moose, kiokudb

What exactly are the weak references that [KiokuDB tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KiokuDB%3a%3aTutorial)  mentions?

How do they differ from 'normal' references?

Comment: Googling "weak references perl" answers the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are weak pointers useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485281/why-are-weak-pointers-useful)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A normal reference prevents the thing being referred to from being garbage collected.  A weak reference is like a normal reference, but does not prevent garbage collection.  When the last normal reference to an entity is removed, it gets garbage collected, and any weak references to it become `undef`.

This is useful if you have circular references.  A reference-count garbage collector (like Perl uses) cannot remove things with circular references, because their reference count never goes to 0.

For example, consider a tree structure, where parent nodes have references to their child nodes, and child nodes have a reference to their parent.  By making the child-to-parent references weak, the tree will be automatically garbage collected when there are no external references to it.

In Perl, weak references can be created with [the `weaken` function in Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil#weaken).  [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) also allows you to mark attributes as [weak_ref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aAttributes#Weak_references).